# Error Tracking in Amazon SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a custom Image Classifier in Amazon SageMaker. It is giving me the following error:

`"ClientError: Data download failed:NoSuchKey (404): The specified key does not exist."`

I'm assuming this means one of the pictures in my `.lst` file is missing from the directory. Is there some way to find out which `.lst` listing it is specifically having trouble with?

Comment: Can you explain or better post the relevant code in the question? It seems like your trying to download some files from s3 but that's all I can tell. How about printing all key names before download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further examination (of the log files), it appears the issue does not lie with the .lst file itself, but with the image files it was referencing (which now leaves me wondering why AWS doesn't just say that instead of saying the .lst file is corrupt). I'm going through the image files one-by-one to verify they are correct, hopefully that will solve the problem.